# How does `curl` access SSL certs in macOS?

Tags: curl, macos, https

I'm on a Macbook with macOS 10.15.5. I have MacPorts, but I am using the 'native' version of `curl`.

```bsh
% curl --version
curl 7.64.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0) libcurl/7.64.1 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/2.8.3 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.39.2
Release-Date: 2019-03-27
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets
```

When I try to d/l the latest `youtube-dl`, I get a certificate error:

```
% sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I did take a look at the 'web page mentioned above', but I did not find a solution. The youtube-dl maintainers at GitHub are adamant that their cert is valid and up-to-date. They offered [this document as "the answer"](https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117LT), but I found nothing useful in it. `curl` is able to download other SSL webpages without issue, and so I believe the issue is particular to this certificate/website.

I've never had this issue. I have an older Macbook with Mojave - I've updated or re-installed `youtube-dl` several times without incident, but it also fails now. However, I can run this same `curl` command on my Ubuntu Linux box, and it works fine. I have to guess this means that both Macs are "missing something" - something that the Mojave Mac once had, but has been removed.

What do I need to do to the Macs to get `curl` to handle SSL certificates?

Comment: See https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2020-06/0010.html and related messages. You can use `curl -k` to disable the certificate check.

Comment: @nohillside: Hello again! :)  Yeah - I saw the disable option, but I want to get this configured properly. If that means adding a CA or a cert, I'd prefer to do that. Also want to understand *why* this happened, how to fix in the future.

Comment: According to the curl mailing list it's an issue with LibreSSL. Loading new CA/certs didn't work for me. I've installed the homebrewed version of curl now (it's keg-only so you need to adjust your PATH), it doesn't have the issue.

Comment: @nohillside: Please prepare an answer with that info; particularly how to load CA/certs. I guess if it's a bug with LibreSSL, then it will be resolved soon??? I use MacPorts, not `homebrew`, so that's not going to work for me. And unfortunately, the MacPorts version does have the issue. That's good info - thanks!

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html documents how to load CA/certs but as I said it didn't solve the problem for me. So I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @nohillside: AFAIC, if the answer provides the correct steps, but fails due to a bug in the `LibreSSL` library, it's still a correct answer. And you've provided the alternative - `homebrew`. I can't use `homebrew` but it's still a correct answer. You did the work, you should get the credit. Only caveat: if a better answer is provided, I'll have to give it the "check".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with expired certificates and LibreSSl, according to https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2020-06/0010.html. Possible workarounds are

- Use `curl -k` at impacted web sites. This disables certificate checking though, so it has some risks
- (on Catalina) Set `CURL_SSL_BACKEND=secure-transport`
- (on all macOS versions) Run `brew install curl` and set the PATH to pick up the homebrew version with `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"`

PS: You can also try to load new certificates by following the instructions on https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html but I got the same error even after loading them.

PPS: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232445/https-connection-to-specific-sites-fail-with-curl-on-macos has a lot more on this, including alternative solutions like removing the `AddTrust` certificate from `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`.

Comment: An incredibly messy situation, IMHO. It sounds from [this reference](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2020-06/0010.html) that it's a "flaw" that affects multiple libraries. Also appears to call into question [claims made by OpenBSD re LibreSSL](http://www.openbsd.org/papers/libtls-fsec-2015/mgp00005.html). Then again, ["cross-signed certificates" sounds a bit wobbly](https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117LT) to me also.